# how to check whether my text field is allowing more than 15 characters or not in protractor for angular js app

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a text field.If the entered character limit exceeds 15 ,I have to check whether it is showing the correct error message or not.

Comment: <div input-container placeholder="Name" error="name.$error" >
                            <input fr-validate type="text" name="Name" class="form-

control border-radius-0" ng-maxlength="15" ng-model="FirstName" />
                        </div>

Comment: check as validate? check as limit? or check as know in js?

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear your question but if you need to show the right error you need something like this:

```
<form name="formName">
   <input fr-validate type="text" name="Name" class="form- control border-radius-0" ng-maxlength="15" ng-model="FirstName" />
   <p ng-show="formName.Name.$error.maxlength">Name is too long</p>
</form>
```

The `p` will be show if you exceed the length.

Comment: i want to test this functionality is working or not by using protractor.